# For an $n$ dimensional hypercube, how many corner points are required such that all other corner points are at most 1 edge away

Tags: general-topology, algebra-precalculus, geometry, graph-theory

For example, given $n=2$, we only need 2 points, (for example (0,0) and (1,1)), such that any other corner can be reached by only traveling 1 edge at max. For $n=3$ this is true as well that only 2 points are needed.

However this is not the case for $n=4$, is there an easily generalized formula for the number of points required to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to give a formula for a lower bound:  each selected point accounts for itself and $n$ neighbors, so at least $\big\lceil \frac{2^n}{n+1}\big\rceil$ points are required. For $n=4$, this gives $4$, which is correct.  (The points could be $(0,0,0,0), (0,1,1,1), (1,0,0,0)$ and $(1,1,1,1)$, for example.)

Unfortunately, this lower bound cannot always be achieved.  For $n=5$, the lower bound gives $6$, but $7$ points are actually needed.  The values for $n \le 9$ are given in OEIS sequence [A000983](http://oeis.org/A000983), but the sequence is labelled "hard" which suggests that not only is there no exact formula known, but also no efficient method for computing further values.  Even for $n=10$, the answer is not known.

A significant exception (duly noted on the sequence's page) is that when $n$ is of the form $2^k - 1$ the lower bound can be achieved.  In this case, the minimal covering of the $n$-hypercube corresponds to a [Hamming code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code).